# facebook page plugin not displayed on wix.com website

Tags: facebook, iframe, plugins

I am trying to add an iframe pointing to my facebook feed on a wix.com website. 
Unfortunately, it does not display anything.

On wixsite, I added an html iframe control and pasted code generated by this site : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsentiersdenfance%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

but it does not display anything on my wix.com site.

I tried this iframe also here but it is not display although : https://jsbin.com/walewaxayi/edit?html,output

Do you see what could I forgotten ?

Comment: Works fine for me in your jsbin. Make sure that you have no browser extensions / native browser settings blocking “trackers” or anything like that.

Comment: @CBroe, yes it was my browser which was blocking faceboook tracking (firefox facebook container in my case). Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

just to close my question, thank to @CBroe who helped me by pointing problems linked to "trackers blocker".

But it was not the only problem. 
On https://jsbin.com/walewaxayi/edit?html,output, problem was solved.

But on Wix.com, my plugin were still empty.

I finally achieved to display it by setting differently my wix.com iframe control

I had to set "website adress" ("Adresse du site" in french) with this code :

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FmyWebsite%2F&tabs=events&width=500&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=false&appId
```

rather than by "code" (Code in french) with code given by facebook :

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsentiersdenfance%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

[html control setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftmaP.png)